# App Store Submission: Can I modify the standard EULA?

Tags: app-store

I need to add an extra condition to the standard EULA.  Am I allowed to copy and add to the existing [EULA](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/)?  Or is this a copyright violation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the EULA for the app store. You either accept it or don't get to publish.

You shouldn't copy someone else EULA. You should just write your own. The Apple EULA is going to have a copyright on it the same way that any code you write you automatically have a copyright on it even if you don't put a copyright notice on it.

Comment: I mean the EULA for the user.  The license that the user (using my app) agrees to.  More specifically, the app store submission process asks you if you want to use the standard EULA (link above) or a custom EULA.  I'm happy with the standard, except of the fact that I need to add one sentence.